# No me funciona video en Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap, video

Un gran saludo:

He tenido una dificultad, ya que este vídeo que inserto me sale la imagen del vídeo pero no se reproduce, lo estoy haciendo con **Bootstrap 4** de la siguiente manera, no se ¿por que no se reproduce?

Gracias

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video class="video"src="imagenes/videos/intro.mp4" autoplay loop/>
</div>
```

Comment: tuve un problema similar..primero que nada debes ver la compatibilidad de los diferentes formatos de video para cada navegador, aparte de ello que tu source o url del video este bien definido...tambien que el navegador este actualizado...

Comment: Gracias, pues estuve mirando y cambie la etiqueta de vídeo a la etiqueta iframe, y funciono, pero no totalmente, por ejemplo la propiedad autoplay no sirve, ni la de loop, no se ¿por que será?, el vídeo es mp4 y es con Botstrap 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, creo que lo que planteas no tiene errores de sintaxis, a lo mucho la definición de la clase "video" está pegado con la definición del atributo src, pero nada que afecte al funcionamiento de la etiqueta.

Como puedes apreciar en el siguiente extracto, estoy utilizando tu misma estructura HTML (ignora la etiqueta link, es sólo para importar Bootstrap 4), con la única diferencia de que en el src definí la ruta a un vídeo válido para el reproductor.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video class="video"src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4" autoplay loop/>
</div>
```

Haz lo que te sugiere Tegito123:

> [...] primero que nada debes ver la compatibilidad de los diferentes formatos de video para cada navegador, aparte de ello que tu source o url del video este bien definido [...]

Answer (score 0):

estas utilizando mal la etiqueta `video` debería ser así (como consejo siempre setea el width o height)

```
<video width="400" autoplay loop>
  <source src="imagenes/videos/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: Esto no es correcto, el usuario está poniendo el atributo [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/video#attr-src) que es válido y sirve para especificar la fuente del video sin necesidad de usar etiquetas `<source>`.

Comment: No estoy deacuerdo en setear el tamaño del reproductor, al menos no en este caso ya que al hacerlo estarías sobrescribiendo las propiedades de tamaño responsivos que Bootstrap intentará definir.